# Keep line formatting in browser with bash CGI

Tags: bash, browser, formatting, cgi

I'm using this bash CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo `ls -al`
```

And it produces ie:

> total 52 drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 4096 Feb 2 18:34 . drwxr-xr-x. 8 root
>   root 4096 Feb 2 17:58 .. -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 36310 Feb 2 17:45
>   dds.jpg -rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user 50 Feb 2 18:03 dds_panel.htm
>   -rwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 460 Feb 2 18:34 test-cgi.cgi

In a terminal they appear each neatly on a single line but in the browser they appear all on the same line. What's the best way to keep the formatting?

Comment: You could just use `<pre>` tags to preserve the whitespace in the output. It seems like you're reinventing something like Apache's [directory listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings), though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need any html formatting, simply change the content-type to `text/plain`.

If you need html formatting your output should contain a complete html page. In this case surround your output with `<pre>`, replace newlines with `<br>` or convert your output in something like a list or table.