# Preserving line breaks and formatting with BASH CGI

Tags: linux, bash, browser, cgi

I tried this (text/plain content):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo `ls -al`
```

And this (html content with `<pre>` tags):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "<pre>"
echo `ls -al`
echo "</pre>"
```

In both cases my Bash CGI is outputting everything on one line in my browser's output.

How can I preserve the formatting as in a terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep line formatting in browser with bash CGI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284475/keep-line-formatting-in-browser-with-bash-cgi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
echo `ls -al`
```

Just use:

```
ls -al
```

so that all the newlines are preserved in output also.

Your `echo` command is unquoted hence causes shell to convert all newlines and multiple spaces into a single space.